# can't access my spring-boot end-points from public ip address

Tags: spring-boot, http, router, firewall, portforwarding

i built a java project (spring-boot)
which works perfectly on my localhost.
I expose some end-points with GET verb, like :
http://localhost:8193/v1/interactive/live/check

I choosed port 8193 to be accessed from the internet,
as my internet provider let me do a port forwarding on my internet box.
(authorized range is 8193 to 16383 so i choosed 8193)

So i made a port forwarding as :
external port 8193 ==> internal port 8193 ==> my localhost.

Then, i configured my linux firewall to let port 8193 to come 'in'.

The result of command

```
sudo ufw status
```

is

```
To                         Action      From
----                       ------      --
8193/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8193                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8193/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8193 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Finally,
when i use this internet tool to check if the port can be accessed from the internet,
it says to me it's ok :
https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

But, i can't access the end-point with :
http://87.89.666.777:8193/v1/interactive/live/check
(87.89.666.777 is my fake public adress)

So, what could be bad with my configuration ?